# How to wrap a `futures::Stream` into anything that implements `Write`?

Tags: rust, stream, rusoto

Eventually I will need a `ByteStream` for rusoto. So I thought I can create it from a `futures::Stream`:

```
pub fn z_stream(r: impl Read) -> Result<ByteStream> {
  let outstream = stream::empty();

  // TODO, how do I wrap outstream
  process(r, &mut wrapped_outstream)?;

  Ok(ByteStream::new(outstream))
}
```

I have a method `process` that takes 2 parameters, one for `impl Read`, the other for `impl Write`, where Read and Write come from `std::io`.

How do I wrap the `outstream` above into something that allows me to pass it to `process`? There's probably something already out there and I don't have to write my own wrapper?

Comment: Does the `process` function run synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: You are aware of the `into_blocking_read()` method for `ByteStream`, right? Have you tried that? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @pretzelhammer, for now sync.  @Coder-256, but the `process()` method needs to write into it, not read from the ByteStream and there isn't a `into_write` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write to a `Stream` in the same way you can't write to an `Iterator`, they are read-only interfaces. You have to write to something else and then have that something else implement the `Stream` trait so it can be read from. In your case, since `process` is sync, you can pass it a `Vec<u8>` buffer to write to and then convert that buffer into a `ByteStream` using the [`From<Vec<u8>>`](https://docs.rs/rusoto_core/0.45.0/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html#impl-From%3CVec%3Cu8%3E%3E) impl:

```rust
use std::io::Write;

pub fn z_stream(r: impl Read) -> Result<ByteStream> {
  let buffer: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

  process(r, &mut buffer)?; // &mut Vec<u8> impls io::Write

  Ok(buffer.into()) // ByteStream has From<Vec<u8>> impl
}
```